# Output variable value in a string

Tags: python, string

In Ruby I can do this:

```
"This is a string with the value of #{variable} shown."
```

How do I do that same thing in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of options.

```
"This is a string with the value of " + str(variable) + " shown."

"This is a string with the value of %s shown." % (str(variable))

"This is a string with the value of {0} shown.".format(variable)
```

Answer (score 3):

The modern/preferred way is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
"This is a string with the value of {} shown.".format(variable)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> 'abc{}'.format(123)
'abc123'
>>>
```

Note that in Python versions before 2.7, you need to explicitly number the format fields:

```
"This is a string with the value of {0} shown.".format(variable)
```

Comment: @C.B.: 2.7 and up, actually.

Comment: @MartjinPieters really? I tried that on 2.7 and it threw errors at me. Maybe it was 2.6

Answer (score 1):

this is one of the way we can also do

```
from string import Template
s = Template('$who likes $what')
s.substitute(who='tim', what='kung pao')
```

Comment: Also good, though possibly overkill for his particular example.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense i thought same answer as you but your quick.do it first or do it different :)